# Creating XML file for Google Maps API markers error

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I've been trying to generate an XML document that contains the markers for my Google Map, to do this I've used Google's developer  [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3).

My code:

```
<?php
// Start XML file, create parent node

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node); 

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server

$connection=mysql_connect('localhost','root');
if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());} 

// Set the active MySQL database

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('maplocations', $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
} 

// Select all the rows in the markers table

$query = "SELECT * FROM location WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {  
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} 

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE  
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");  
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);   
  $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);  
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);  
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);  
  $newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
} 

echo $dom->save('google.xml');

?>
```

The error I'm getting while executing this is the following:

```
error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
```

I've already set the header to output text for debugging, and it no longer generates any errors. Help please?

Comment: I suspect you want [`->saveXML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) rather than simply `->save()`

Comment: have you checked the xml output to see if there's anything bad formated or strange character that doesn't match the defined encoding?

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone and can not be combined to create terms.  For example, combining `google`, `maps` and `api` doesn't mean you're talking about the Google Maps API.